# Write both signed and unsigned char to write()

Tags: c++, binary, signed

I am trying communicate with a Simplebgc board via serial on my Raspberry Pi.  I am writing commands to the board using an array of unsigned char to represent byes.  The following command only needs unsigned bytes so the following works but if I want to send a command that needs a mix of both unsigned and signed bytes how do I do it?

```
void sendCommand() {
    int fd;

    if ((fd = serialOpen ("/dev/ttyS0", 115200)) < 0) {
        //fprintf (stderr, "Unable to open serial device: %s\n", strerror (errno));
        cout<<"Unable to open serial device"<<endl;
        return;
    }

    unsigned char board_info[6] = {0x3E, 0x56, 0x01, 0x57, 0x01, 0x01};  //BOARD_INFO

    serialFlush(fd);

    // Send command to grab board info
    write(fd, board_info, 6);
    sleep(2);

    // Read board response and print it
    char c;
    int counter = 0;
    while (read(fd, &c, 1) == 1) {
        //putchar(c);  // print out char    
        printf("%d ",c);
        counter++;
    }
    cout<<"\ncounter="<<counter<<endl;
    sleep(5);


}

int main() {
    sendCommand();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A byte is a byte. Whether it's signed or unsigned is entirely a figment of your imagination. If you think it's signed, it's signed. If you think it's unsigned, it's unsigned. Just figure out the raw groups of 8 bits that you need to send, and send it without worrying about their alleged signedness. `0xE0 0x40 0x73` (just some bytes at random) are completely identical, whether these bytes are signed or unsigned.

Comment: So I should convert it manually is that what your saying?  Write the unsigned representation of the signed version in my array?

Comment: Have you tried changing "unsigned char board_info" to "char board_info"?

Comment: On current Linux distributions, the 2nd parameter to the `write()` system call is a `void *`. So do whatever makes you happy: create either a signed char array, or an unsigned char array, and fill it out with whatever data you wish to send. Then pass it to `write()`. I give you my personal guarantee that `write()` will not give a fig about whether these bytes were signed or unsigned, to start with. The only thing that matters, in the end, is that they are collections of 8 bits. How you interpret those 8 bits is entirely up to you.